# Why "I have been young" in Psalm 37?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, tzaddikim

The psalmist said, in a line we also recite in *birkat hamazon*:

> נַ֤עַר ׀ הָיִ֗יתִי גַּם־זָ֫קַ֥נְתִּי וְֽלֹא־רָ֭אִיתִי צַדִּ֣יק נֶעֱזָ֑ב וְ֝זַרְע֗וֹ מְבַקֶּשׁ־לָֽחֶם  -- I have been young, and I am now old; yet I have not seen the righteous abandoned, nor his seed begging for bread. [Ps. 37:25]

The plain meaning can't be right because we have all seen righteous people go through bad times.  Many commentators have provided alternate meanings.  My favorite is from Rav Soloveitchik, who, proceeding by analogy in wording, notes that Queen Esther asks King Achashverosh to spare the Jews using these words:

> כִּ֠י אֵיכָכָ֤ה אוּכַל֙ וְֽרָאִ֔יתִי בָּרָעָ֖ה אֲשֶׁר־יִמְצָ֣א אֶת־עַמִּ֑י וְאֵֽיכָכָ֤ה אוּכַל֙ וְֽרָאִ֔יתִי בְּאָבְדַ֖ן מוֹלַדְתִּֽי
> -- How can I bear to watch the disaster which will befall my people, and how can I bear to watch the destruction of my family? [Esther 8:6]

The same word (רָ֭אִיתִי - seen) is used in both places, but in the case of Esther, she clearly means: "Can I bear to see all this *and do nothing about it*?"  Likewise, the line in Psalms means: "I have not seen the righteous abandoned, nor his seed begging for bread *and done nothing about it*."

OK, now my question.  What does the line "I have been young" add to the thought?  "I am old" should be sufficient.  I have not seen a commentary on this.  I believe the answer may hold yet another meaning.  Do you know of one?

Comment: From a plain reading of the text it seems that this line emphasises the life experience of the author and adds some authority to the proceeding statement. "I went from being young to now being old and yet [....]

Comment: Just to clarify- are you asking what that phrase means according to the explanation of Rav Soloveitchik which you quote? Or are you asking according to any explanation of the verse?

Comment: @Binyomin -- Any explanation.  Line seems unnecessary given all explanations I know.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have checked this truth even way back when I was a youth.

Ibn Ezra on Psalms 37:25:1

נער - ניסיתי זה בנעורי וזקנתי.

---

2. In all periods of life, my youth and my old age, I have examined what became of the righteous.

Metzudat David on Psalms 37:25:1

נער וגו׳‎. ר״‎ל בנערותי ובזקנותי הסתכלתי לראות הנעשה בצדיק:

---

3. Naar might be the name of the Angel Metatron.

Otzar Midrashim, Seventy Names of Metatron 1

שבעים שמות למט״ט: ספר שבעים שמות של מטטרון, שגלה ר׳ ישמעאל כ״ג מה שקבל בעת שעלה למרום, הספר הובא לדפוס ע״י ר׳ משה ב״ר מנחם גראף בשנת 1678 וחסר מקום הדפסתו, וכנראה הוא דפוס אמשטרדם כמו שכתב בעל רב פעלים (צד 93), וכתב שם עוד וז״ל: חז״ל אמרו א״ר שמואל בר נחמני א״ר יונתן פסוק זה שר של העולם אמרו, נער הייתי גם זקנתי (תהילים ל״ז:כ״ה), ועי׳ תוס׳ ד״ה פסוק זה וגו׳ ומסיק ובפסיקתא בח׳ (צ״ל בע׳) שמות של מטטרון מונה נמי נער עכ״ל. ובחולין (ס׳.) התוס׳ ד״ה פסוק זה וכו׳ אמרו א״נ מה שקרא הפייטן למטטרון נער לא בשביל הפסוק נער הייתי אלא לפי שכתוב בספר יוסיפון דלמטטרון יש שבע (צ״ל שבעים) שמות וחשיב נער עכ״ל. ולא נמצא בספר יוסיפון שלנו, ובודאי ט"ס הוא.

Comment: i used sefaria of course

Comment: As this is an English site, it's recommended that you bring the translations of these texts, or translate them yourself.